# Calling an Object in a Collections.frequency method from a different class within a different method

Tags: java

//This is class App where I created object A

App.java

```
Product A = new Product(name:"ThisIsAName",price: 3);
```

---

// This is class Register where i want to call A from class App at 'ThisIsWhereIWantToCallA' to be able to count the number of times A occurs in an array list called Basket from a specific customer.

However, if i simply put A at ThisIsWhereIWantToCallA, i get: cannot resolve symbol 'A'.

Register.java

```
public void calculateAmountPerProduct(Customer customer) {

   int amountOfA = Collections.frequency(customer.getBasket(), ThisIsWhereIWantToCallA);
   System.out.println("Frequency of A:" + amountOfA);
```

How do i correctly call A from App.java?

Answer (score 0):

**App class:**

```
public class App {
    private Product product;

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }
}
```

**Register class:**

```
public class Register {
    public void calculateAmountPerProduct(Customer customer, App app) {
        int amountOfA = Collections.frequency(customer.getBasket(), app.getProduct());
        System.out.println("Frequency of A:" + amountOfA);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        App app = new App();
        Register register = new Register();
        Customer customer = new Customer();

        app.setProduct(new Product("ThisIsAName", 3));

        register.calculateAmountPerProduct(customer, app);
    }
}
```